# Entity deletion not working as intended

Tags: c++, entity

I'm trying to write an Entity Component System that will let me use a manager class to create and delete Entity classes at will, without having to worry too much about memory management after completion.

It looks something like this:

```
class Entity {
    int testInt = 0;
public:
    Test(int a) {
        testInt = a;
    }

    int getTestInt() { return testInt; }
}


class EntityManager {
public:
    inline static std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Entity> > EntityVector = {};

    static Entity& createEntity(int a) {
        auto* e = new Entity(a);
        EntityVector.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Entity>(e));
        return *e;
    }

    // should delete an entity through erasing its unique_ptr
    // by comparing the testInt value to the given argument
    static void destroyEntity(int a) {
    EntityVector.erase(
                std::remove_if(
                        EntityVector.begin(),
                        EntityVector.end(),
                        [a] (const std::unique_ptr<Entity> &currentEntity) -> bool {
                            return currentEntity->getTestInt() == a;
                        }),
                EntityVector.end()
        );
    }

};
```

The whole thing is larger, but this part produces the issue.

Now when I create an `Entity` with the `EntityManager::createEntity()` everything works fine, but when I go to delete the `Entity` either manually through `delete` or through the `destroyEntity` function I wrote, it does not seem to get deleted, even though to my knowledge, deleting a `unique_ptr` calls the destructor of the object it is pointing to. But I can still access the `Entity` after. Here is an example:

```
int a = 5;

Entity testEntity = TestManager::createEntity(a);

// works as expected, outputs 5
std::cout << testEntity.getTestInt() << std::endl;

// does not appear to properly destroy the entity
TestManager::destroyEntity(5); // same thing happens with a passed as an argument

// still prints 5
std::cout << testEntity.getTest() << std::endl;
```

Which outputs

```
5
5
```

My question is: Why does the deletion of the `std::unique_ptr<Entity>` not actually delete the `Entity` it is pointing to?

Comment: When storing the entity from createEntity (), you currently create a copy. To store a reference, declare testEntity as a Entity&

Comment: If you make `testEntity` a `Entity&` as the previous comment suggests, then the line `testEntity.getTest()` (I assume it's meant to be `getTestInt()`) is undefined behavior and may do anything, including print 5.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You're right. After some testing, it seems it's now completely random whether the correct number is printed or not.

Comment: You should probably avoid storing references to entities like this, as you will get into trouble with dangling references.